# Using SharePointPnPCoreOnline with Azure Function

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-dev-pnp, azure-functions

I am creating my first Azure Function(with .net core 3.0) with SharePointPnPCoreOnline package. When I created a function project without SharePointPnPCoreOnline its working without any error.

But when I added SharePointPnPCoreOnline its started giving me warning message like below

> Warning   NU1701  Package 'SharePointPnPCoreOnline 3.18.2002' was
>   restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework
>   '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0'. This package may not be fully compatible
>   with your
>   project.  CRB.Functions   C:\Ravi\Source\Functions\Functions.csproj   1

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SharePointPnPCoreOnline` is a wrapper around CSOM, which is not compatible with .NET Core without a bit of hacking.

You need to use full .NET Framework, and V1 of the Functions runtime, in order to use that Nuget package with Azure Functions.

Comment: Thanks @Derek. Also facing issues with V1 as well but will post a separate question on that.

Comment: I've done a ton of PnP/Azure Functions. I'll keep an eye out for the question.

Comment: Thanks @Derek. I am stuck with Azure Function V1 as well. Posted separate question https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/276468/using-sharepointpnpcoreonline-with-azure-functionv1